# Find the set with the desired items having the minimum score

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I was working on a problem and I've got stuck with my data structures at a point. Here is the problem:

I have a **list** of n **tuples**(each tuple containing a **set** of some items and a weight associated with that set). The set inside the tuple can contain any number of items(or no items at all). Also, I have one set which contains all the desired items. Let me give a sample of the data to clarify further:

```
desired_set = set(['item1', 'item2', 'item3'])

list_of_tuples = [
                  (12.0, set(['item1', 'item3'])),
                  (3.5, set(['item3'])),
                  (5.0, set(['item2'])),
                  (7.2, set(['item1'])),
                  (10.0, set(['item2', 'item3']))
                 ]
```

Now, I need to combine these sets to obtain all possible **desired sets**. When the sets will combine, their weight will be added. For example, for the above data:

`(12.0, set(['item1', 'item3']))` and `(5.0, set(['item2']))` will give `(17.0, set(['item1', 'item2', 'item3']))`

`(5.0, set(['item1']))`, `(7.2, set(['item2']))` and `(3.5, set(['item3']))` will give `(15.7, set(['item1', 'item2', 'item3']))`

`(7.2, set(['item1']))` and `(10.0, set(['item2', 'item3']))` will give `(17.2, set(['item1', 'item2', 'item3']))`

I need to obtain all such possible tuples(where set is same as a desired_set) in a new list so that I can **find the one with the minimum score**. Any help(code, algo, advice, guidance) is very much appreciated.

Comment: If using a set from the list of tuples would bring a needed item, but also duplicate an existing one, is that valid or not valid?   IE is the composition of 3.5, 5 and 10 a valid possible possble tuple?

Comment: I just need to find the combination(containing all the desired items) with the minimum score. Yes, 3.5, 5 and 10 can also give us an eligible tuple. No problem with that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is NP-complete. There's a trivial reduction from the [set cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) to this problem by just setting all weights to 1. You're not going to write a fast, exact solution. You could try approximation algorithms, backtracking search, or existing optimization problem solvers. A quick Google search for `set cover solver` turned up [Microsoft Solver Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/hh145003.aspx), which might work for you.

If you want to do this yourself, and you want an exact solution, [backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) would do it. You build up the list of tuples one at a time. For each tuple, you decide whether to include it or not include it; you can pick arbitrarily, though best performance would arise from an intelligent decision. When you determine that the decisions you've made can't result in the optimal solution - perhaps because you've already exceeded the weight of a better solution you found earlier - you backtrack to the last decision you made and pick a different option. You also backtrack if the tuples you've chosen include all the items you wanted. If you already tried all possibilities for a decision, you go back to the last decision for which you haven't tried all possibilities. When you're completely out of things to try, the best solution you found during the whole procedure is the best solution possible.

Comment: Greedy algorithm for set cover doesn't guarantee the minimum possible weight. Right? Which algorithm I should use then?

Comment: @ManishJain: I've included an explanation of a backtracking algorithm that would do the job, if you want to write this yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my *portable* advice for the most rock-solid way to get an exact answer (as opposed to approximation), albeit not the fastest:

1. Create a list of all possible sets, there will be `Sum(C(n, i) for i=0..n) = 2^n` values (this is where the complexity arises).
   *This is the sum of n choose i, where i is each integer from 0 to n (inclusive)*
   i.e. for 5 values (like in your example) = 32 sets
2. Sort the new list by weight, or use an appropriate algorithm for the first step that already does that.
3. Starting from the lowest weight set, iterate over the list and your final answer will be the first set you encounter that satisfies your `desired_set`

Overall, this algorithm will take O(2^n) (exponential) time and space. The implications of this are that **the time and space requirements double for each additional value in the `list_of_tuples`**.

The advantages here are that there are no restrictions on the contents of `desired_set` or `list_of_tuples`.

Here is more than enough sample code to get you started, you will have to add the code to generate combinations of 3 or more tuples:

```
import itertools

def getLightestDesiredSet(d, a):
    '''(set, list of 2-tuples(float,set)) --> 2-tuple(float,set)
    d is the desired set, a is the list of available sets and their weights
    '''

    '''Part 1 (referencing arocks's answer)'''
    s = set()
    for l in range(0,len(a)):
        for comb in itertools.combinations(a, l):
            result_list.append(( sum([weight for weight, dset in comb]),
                            s.union(*[dset for weight, dset in comb]) ))

    '''Part 2'''
    sorted_result_list = sorted(result_list, key=lambda my_tuple: my_tuple[0])

    '''Part 3'''
    for a_tuple in sorted_result_list:
        if (a_tuple[1].issuperset(desired_set)):
            return a_tuple

    '''if no possible set found: return whatever you want'''
    return(0.0, set())
'''end function'''

desired_set = set(['item1', 'item2', 'item3'])

list_of_tuples = [
                  (12.0, set(['item1', 'item3'])),
                  (3.5, set(['item3'])),
                  (5.0, set(['item2'])),
                  (7.2, set(['item1'])),
                  (10.0, set(['item2', 'item3']))
                 ]
print(getLightestDesiredSet(desired_set, list_of_tuples))
```

I could offer some better advice if you gave me more detail on the restrictions of your situation. For example, will each item always be available individually in the `list_of_tuples` (although not for the best price obviously)?

Comment: This is not the knapsack problem. The nature of the constraint is quite different. Where the knapsack problem asks for the maximum value achievable within a given weight, this problem requires that all items be taken and asks for the minimum weight necessary to do so.

Comment: @user2357112 you're right, I initially misunderstood the question. I'll remove that part

Comment: Thanks Ron for your help. As far as the constraints are concerned, the desired_set and list_of_tuples can contain anything(or nothing at all). So, the data has no restriction over it.

Comment: @ManishJain You're lucky, I've taken it as a personal challenge to solve this problem in a portable manner. And I've found a solution.

Comment: @ManishJain FYI: If I designed your system, I would create a class for items and their weights. Call this an ItemSet, then you can even have an Inventory subclass that limits the total weight. A tuple doesn't suit the data well and leads to data manipulation issues like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use permutations from itertools library to find all combinations. Here is an attempt:

```
from itertools import permutations

result = []
for l in range(1,len(list_of_tuples)):
    for i in permutations(list_of_tuples, l):
        result.append(( sum([weight for weight, dset in i]), 
                        set.union(*[dset for weight, dset in i]) ))
```

`result` will contain all the combinations with weights summed.

Comment: I've corrected your code and included it as an alternative with mine since you have only created the list of all permutations regardless of the desired set. I do like your code though as it is about 1/3 the length of mine!